# OpenGL / OpenTK Drawing with Indices : Attempted to Read or Write Protected Memory Issue

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk, vao

I'm trying to display a quad (or two triangles) with C# and OpenGL. Below is my code for my mesh class. In it you have both the creation of the VBOs and VAO, as well as the function I use to render the mesh.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;
using BuildMe.Core;
using OpenTK;

namespace BuildMe.Render
{
    class Mesh
    {

        private Vector3[] verts;
        private uint[] indices;
        private int instances;
        private int VAO;

        public uint[] Indices { get => indices; set => indices = value; }
        public int Instances { get => instances; set => instances = value; }
        public Vector3[] Verts { get => verts; set => verts = value; }

        public Mesh(Vector3[] verts, uint[] indices, int instances)
        {
            this.verts = verts;
            this.indices = indices;
            this.instances = instances;
            this.VAO = CreateVAO();
            StoreVAOData();
        }

        private int CreateVAO()
        {
            int VAO = GL.GenVertexArray();
            RenderLoop.VAOs.Add(VAO);
            return (VAO);
        }

        private void StoreVAOData()
        {
            GL.BindVertexArray(VAO);

            LoadVerts();
            LoadIndices();

            GL.BindVertexArray(0);
        }

        private void LoadVerts()
        {
            int vbo = GL.GenBuffer();
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vbo);
            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, Vector3.SizeInBytes * verts.Length, verts, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
            GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, Vector3.SizeInBytes, 0);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);
            RenderLoop.VBOs.Add(vbo);
        }

        private void LoadIndices()
        {
            int vbo = GL.GenBuffer();
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, vbo);
            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, sizeof(int) * indices.Length, indices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
            GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 1, VertexAttribPointerType.UnsignedInt, false, sizeof(int), 0);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, 0);
            RenderLoop.VBOs.Add(vbo);
        }

        public int GetVAO()
        {
            return (VAO);
        }

        public void Render()
        {
            GL.BindVertexArray(this.GetVAO());
            GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
            GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(1);
            GL.DrawElements(PrimitiveType.Triangles, this.Indices.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);
            GL.DisableVertexAttribArray(0);
            GL.DisableVertexAttribArray(1);
            GL.BindVertexArray(0);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is where I call the function to render the mesh.

```
        private void Render(object sender, FrameEventArgs e)
        {
            GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.VertexArray);
            GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.IndexArray);
            GL.Color3(Color.Green);
            foreach (Mesh mesh in SceneMeshes)
                mesh.Render();
        }
```

This is the error I'm getting, if it helps. But I think it just means I've either declared the VBOs wrong or I'm using the wrong functions to render it.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in OpenTK.dll
>   Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EnableClientState` and `VertexAttribPointer` do not interact together. If you want to use the client side capabilities, then you have to use `VertexPointer` (see [`glVertexPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertexPointer.xml)):

<s>`GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, Vector3.SizeInBytes, 0);`</s>

```cs
GL.VertexPointer(3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, Vector3.SizeInBytes, 0);
```

`GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.IndexArray);` does not do what you expect. `ArrayCap.IndexArray` is meant for color index attributes.
The index buffer is bound to the target `BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer`. It is not an attribute and has not to be enabled.
Further more the index buffer is stated in the vertex array object. The instruction `GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, 0);` would break the binding:

```cs
private void LoadIndices()
{
    int ibo = GL.GenBuffer();
    GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, ibo);
    GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, sizeof(int) * indices.Length, indices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
    // GL.VertexAttribPointer(...) <--- REMOVE
    // GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, 0); // <--- REMOVE
    RenderLoop.VBOs.Add(ibo);
}
```

The client side capability is stated in the [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object). So it can be stated in `LoadVerts()`:

```
private void LoadVerts()
{
    int vbo = GL.GenBuffer();
    GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vbo);
    GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, Vector3.SizeInBytes * verts.Length, verts, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
    // GL.VertexAttribPointer(...); <---- REMOVE
    GL.VertexPointer(3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, Vector3.SizeInBytes, 0); // <--- ADD
    GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.VertexArray); // <--- ADD
    GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);
    RenderLoop.VBOs.Add(vbo);
}
```

All the necessary specification is stated in the Vertex Array Object, so it is sufficient to bind the VAO, before the draw call:

```cs
public void Render()
{
    GL.BindVertexArray(this.GetVAO());
    GL.DrawElements(PrimitiveType.Triangles, this.Indices.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);
    GL.BindVertexArray(0);
}
```

```cs
private void Render(object sender, FrameEventArgs e)
{
    GL.Color3(Color.Green);
    foreach (Mesh mesh in SceneMeshes)
        mesh.Render();
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help. You explained things super clearly. It's now working as intended.